# How do I write a Regex in Python to remove leading zeros for a number in the middle of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string composed of both letters followed by a number, and I need to remove all the letters, as well as the leading zeros in the number.

For example: in the test string `U012034`, I want to match the `U` and the `0` at the beginning of `012034`.

So far I have `[^0-9]` to match the any characters that aren't digits, but I can't figure out how to also remove the leading zeros in the number.

I know I could do this in multiple steps with something like `int(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", test_string)` but I need this process to be done in one regex.

Comment: Try: `re.sub(r'^[a-zA-Z]*0*|a-zA-Z]+', '', string)`

Comment: I just thought of `[^1-9]`. Would that work?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado that doesn't work for my purpose because that would also remove zeros in the middle of the number. i guess i should clarify that the numbers are integers that matter

Comment: @anubhava your regex works! please feel free to post your comment as an answer and i'll be happy to accept it

Comment: Why not `re.sub(r'^\D*0*', '', text)`?

Comment: @DerekO: You wrote `I need to remove all the letters`. Do you want `U01234BC` to become `1234BC` or `1234`?

Comment: It should become 1234

Comment: ok and what about `U01234BC1`?

Comment: I guess I should clarify that this situation doesn't come up because there is only ever one number in the string

Comment: ok but that clarification should be part of the question because *I have a string composed of both letters and numbers, and I need to remove all the letters, as well as the leading zeros in the numbers.* doesn't give that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'^\D*0*', '', text)
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ZlVBjw/1). *Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `\D*` - any zero or more non-digit chars
- `0*` - zero or more zeros.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dO6pQV):

```py
import re
text = "U012034"
print( re.sub(r'^\D*0*', '', text) )
# => 12034
```

If there is more text after the first number, use

```py
print( re.sub(r'^\D*0*(\d+).*', r'\1', text) )
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZlVBjw/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\D*` - zero or more non-digits
- `0*` - zero or more zeros
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits (use `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` to match float or int values)
- `.* - the rest of the string.

The replacement is the Group 1 value.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `re.sub` in Python:

```sh
string = re.sub(r'^[a-zA-Z]*0*|[a-zA-Z]+', '', string)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AF0yst/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^`: Start
- `[a-zA-Z]*`: Match 0 or more letters
- `0*`L: Match 0 or more zeroes
- `|`: OR
- `[a-zA-Z]+`: Match 1+ of letters

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you need?

```
re.sub("[^0-9]+0*", "", "U0123")
>>> '123'
```

Comment: It will also make `A001B002` to `12`